# Linq entities created at runtime from user-defined view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I would like to use linq2sql in this scenario :

I have a user-defined view in my database whose fields are not known during the design phase.

How can I create a specific entity, during runtime, to use a gridview to show all the view's fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into System.Linq.Expressions for this